# The screenshot in Google Search Console is only text, what does it mean?

Tags: google-search-console

I was inspecting my URL through Google Search Console and in the screenshot section, I see it is only text and images, it looks like the CSS was not applied or so.

Does it mean there's a problem with my site that I should fix? Or is it normal?

Comment: A screenshot of what you're seeing would help.

Comment: how can i send it here?

Comment: Take a screenshot and use the 6th icon from the left to add pics.

Comment: What about `robots.txt`? I suspect we will also need to see the actual website? Is Google able to crawl your stylesheets?